# How to start from a particular line from assets/name.txt file in android

Tags: android, inputstream, bufferedreader, assets

I had taken 10 lines in txt file which is in assets folder (assets/question.txt), From below code I am able to get Line by line from starting of txt file in assets folder. But I want to start from 4 line of txt file. Please help.

```
BufferedReader reader_ques;
        try {
            reader_ques = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("question.txt")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

try {
            line_q = reader_ques.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (line_q != null) 
        {           
            question_tv.setText(line_q);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to read it, ignoring them. For instance:

```
   try {
      for(int i=0 ;i < 4; i++) {
         reader_ques.readLine();
      }
      while ((line_q = reader_ques.readLine()) != null) {
            // do something with line_q
       }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or you can have an ArrayList of string:

```
ArrayList<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<String>();
 try {
       while ((line_q = reader_ques.readLine()) != null) {
               fileContent.add(line_q);
        }
 }
```

in the second case, you have the first row of the file at index 0 of the `ArrayList` and so on

if you want the 5th String you just do

```
String myContent = fileContent.get(5)
```

Comment: I want to display from line number 4 onwards.... is there any way to get line numbers of txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber);
```

try this..

if you have bufferReader then try following

```
LineIterator lineIterator = IOUtils.lineIterator(reader_ques);
 for (int lineNumber = 0; lineIterator .hasNext(); lineNumber++) {
    String line = (String) lineIterator .next();
    if (lineNumber == expectedLineNumber) {
        return line;
    }
 }
```

to use above code you need this library-http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

or this-->http://www.motorlogy.com/apache//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip

Comment: It is showing "LineIterator cannot be resolved to a type" and "IOUtils cannot be resolved"